# XML to XSLT conversion

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have an xml document which has a list of families and a list of familyMembers and later Family to FamilyMember link. I have to create an XSL that displays a HTML table to contents 
in the format
Society
  1. Families
    1.1 FamilyA
      1.1.1 Member1 
      1.1.2 Member4 
    1.2 FamilyB
      1.2.1 Member2 
      1.2.2 Member3 
      1.2.3 Member5 
      1.2.4 Member6

Clicking on the link should navigate to the corresponding portion of the page. Please help me to resolve this

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <society>
        <families>
            <family>
                <name>A</name>
                <numberofMembers>2</numberofMembers>
                <Description>abc</Description>
                <place></place>
            </family>
            <family>
                <name>B</name>
                <numberofMembers>4</numberofMembers>
                <Description>xyz</Description>
                <place></place>
            </family>
        </families>
        <familyMembers>
            <familyMember>
            <name>member1</name>
            <occupation>blah</occupation>
            <ID>1</ID>
            </familyMember>
            <familyMember>
                <name>ghij</name>
                <occupation>blah2</occupation>
                <ID>2</ID>
            </familyMember>
            <familyMember>
                <name>member2</name>
                <occupation>blah3</occupation>
                <ID>3</ID>
            </familyMember>
            <familyMember>
                <name>member3</name>
                <occupation>bgd</occupation>
                <ID>4</ID>
            </familyMember>
            <familyMember>
                <name>member4</name>
                <occupation>sdjhf</occupation>
                <ID>5</ID>
            </familyMember>
            <familyMember>
                <name>member5</name>
                <occupation>member6</occupation>
                <ID>6</ID>
            </familyMember>
        </familyMembers>
        <FamilyFamilyMembers>
            <FamilyFamilyMember>
                <source>
                    /families/A
                </source>
                <target>
                    /familyMember/member1
                </target>
            </FamilyFamilyMember>
            <FamilyFamilyMember>
                <source>
                    /families/A
                </source>
                <target>
                    /familyMember/member4
                </target>
            </FamilyFamilyMember>
            <FamilyFamilyMember>
                <source>
                    /families/B
                </source>
                <target>
                    /familyMember/member2
                </target>
            </FamilyFamilyMember>
            <FamilyFamilyMember>
                <source>
                    /families/B
                </source>
                <target>
                    /familyMember/member3
                </target>
            </FamilyFamilyMember>
            <FamilyFamilyMember>
                <source>
                    /families/B
                </source>
                <target>
                    /familyMember/member5
                </target>
            </FamilyFamilyMember>
            <FamilyFamilyMember>
                <source>
                    /families/A
                </source>
                <target>
                    /familyMember/member6
                </target>
            </FamilyFamilyMember>
        </FamilyFamilyMembers>
    </society>
```

Comment: Read ALL the faq's here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Can you please share me some examples of similar kind if you have any?

Comment: Are you constrained to XSLT 1.0? Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I am supposed to use XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT 1.0 solution only addresses the problem of organising your data. I have not concerned myself with the html rendering, as this is a trivial exercise which is best left to the OP. This solution uses a for-each and variable declarations to unwrap the relational form of the input document to the required hierarchical form in the output. If you need an XSLT 2.0 solution, let us know, as an XSLT 20 solution will be much simpler and smaller.

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Families>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="society/families/family"/>
  </Families>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="family">
 <xsl:variable name="family-name" select="name" />
 <family family-name="{name}">
  <xsl:variable name="roster" select="../../FamilyFamilyMembers/FamilyFamilyMember
       [normalize-space( substring-after( source, '/families/')) = $family-name]
      " />
    <xsl:for-each select="../../familyMembers/familyMember">
     <xsl:variable name="person-name" select="name" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select= "self::node()[
      count( $roster[normalize-space( substring-after( target, '/familyMember/')) = $person-name]) >= 1
      ]" /> 
    </xsl:for-each>  
 </family>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="familyMember">
  <family-member member-name="{name}" /> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... when applied to the sample input, will produce ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Families>
  <family family-name="A">
    <family-member member-name="member1" />
    <family-member member-name="member4" />
  </family>
  <family family-name="B">
    <family-member member-name="member2" />
    <family-member member-name="member3" />
    <family-member member-name="member5" />
  </family>
</Families>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I was missing one step that was screwing me .....